# How to install Commerce 2 on Drupal VM?

Tags: 8, commerce, composer

I have a virtual machine running with a standard install of Drupal 8 on windows. See [Drupal VM](https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm#quick-start-guide)

I want to install [Drupal Commerce 2](http://docs.drupalcommerce.org/v2/getting-started/install.html) on the VM.

Do i use composer like the Commerce instructions say (composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base mystore --stability dev).

If so where? In de folder on windows that I installed the VM in, or in the part after i use vagrant ssh (vagrant@drupalvm:~$).

Or do i need to customize one of the .yml files and then do a vagrant provision?

Please help. (sorry if I am to noob)

Answer (score 1):

Like the Commerce docs say, you need to install it like any other Drupal 8 site. So, it is easier to use the composer command.

`composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base MYNEWSITE --stability dev`

Where MYNEWSITE is the new Drupal 8 w Commerce 2 directory. You can do this anywhere on the host machine (ex. I always have them in /Sites).

From here, you can add Drupal VM to the project and tailor the config.yml to your needs, then `vagrant up` - just like you did with the vanilla Drupal 8 site you already installed. You should see the Commerce install screen.

There is likely a way to automate this with DrupalVM, though I have not tried that approach.